# Checkbox display is not changing with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have some values that post back to a parent form from a child form and fire this method

```
function OnClientClose(oWnd, args) {
    //get the transferred arguments
    var arg = args.get_argument();
    if (arg) {
        var agreementId = $find("<%= rtxtAgreementId.ClientID %>");
        var legacyReinsurerId = $find("<%= rtxtlegacyReinsurerId.ClientID %>");

        agreementId.set_value(arg.ReinsuranceAgreementId);
        legacyReinsurerId.set_value(arg.LegacyReinsurerId);
        $("<%= chkCommutationFlag.ClientID %>").prop("checked", Boolean(arg.CommutationFlag));
    }
};
```

all arguments have the proper values including Boolean(arg.CommutationFlag) as I tested this by displaying the value in a textbox, but my checkbox display value does not change. I have tried various methods to set the checkbox value and they all process without throwing an error but the checkbox remains unchecked. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it sounds dumb, but what event is `OnClientClose`? Are you using any third party components like Telerik?

Comment: Yes, is is a RadWindow on close event handler. My values display great in the textboxes using the set_value method. I just can't get the chdckbox to change state.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.prop` was added in 1.6.

Comment: 1.6.1. I did try prop. it seemed to work but the display didn't show correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by checking if you are actually hitting the target, replace prop with some mundane css instead to see if the checkbox changes apperance.
If it does'nt your ID is wrong, and remember that you need # before the ID.
If it does change, replace your boolean with the actual word "true", if that fixes it your boolean is wrong, and it's probably one or the other.

Just to make sure you could place an alert right above your checkbox code to see that your script is getting that far, but if the console shows no errors, and if the css approach works, that's not it.

Comment: Thats great, then you know where the problem is by process of elimination. I'm assuming it works with an actual ID and the actual word "true" in your jQuery function?

Comment: using $("#DataEntry1_chkCommutationFlag").prop("checked", true); the value is set when the method completes. The debugged jquery code is lacking the # $("DataEntry1_chkCommutationFlag").prop("checked", Boolean(arg.CommutationFlag)); Thanks I overlooked.